# WifiNetworkSpecifier is not able to provide Internet Access

Tags: android, wifi

I am using this code to request a network that is already saved in Wi-Fi saved networks list. I am able to connect to the network but I am not able to access internet. It always says connected without internet. And after this, if I go to Wi-Fi settings and disconnect from the network and again connect (manually) everything works fine.

```
    private void requestNetwork(String tempId, String tempPass) {
    WifiNetworkSpecifier specifier;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        specifier = new WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder()
                .setSsid(tempId)
                .setWpa2Passphrase(tempPass)
                .build();

        NetworkRequest request = new NetworkRequest.Builder()
                .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
                .setNetworkSpecifier(specifier)
                .build();
        connectivityManager.requestNetwork(request, new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onAvailable(@NonNull Network network) {
                super.onAvailable(network);
                connectivityManager.bindProcessToNetwork(network);
                Log.i("tag", "Network is available, and maybe I am connected to it");
            }
        });
    }
}
```